# How to convert a float into a byte array and vice versa?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a `float` into a primitive `byte[]` and vice versa:

```
public byte[] floatToByteArray(final float value)
{
    return new byte[]
    {
        (byte) (value >> 56),
        (byte) (value >> 48),
        (byte) (value >> 40),
        (byte) (value >> 32),
        (byte) (value >> 24),
        (byte) (value >> 16),
        (byte) (value >> 8),
        (byte) (value)
    };
}
```

Oddly enough, when I try to shift the newly allocated `byte[]` back into a `float`, the result is nothing but rubbish.

However, it would appear as if the same algorithm works just fine when I use the primitive `long` data type as argument instead.

```
public byte[] longToByteArray(final long value)
{
    return new byte[]
    {
        (byte) (value >> 56),
        (byte) (value >> 48),
        (byte) (value >> 40),
        (byte) (value >> 32),
        (byte) (value >> 24),
        (byte) (value >> 16),
        (byte) (value >> 8),
        (byte) (value)
    };
}
```

Comment: how did you test the function ?

Comment: did you append `f` in the end of the test data float2ByteArray (3.4f)

Comment: I'm starting to like C now. `char* floatAsByte = (char*)&myFloat;`

Comment: Floats are 32 bit, so get the int bits http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits(float) and use a similar method as you did for long, but instead with int.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use these instead.

```
public static byte [] long2ByteArray (long value)
{
    return ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array();
}

public static byte [] float2ByteArray (float value)
{  
     return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(value).array();
}
```

Comment: Could you pls also provide more information regarding the package to import? we have two options Java.nio and java.sum.corba

Comment: ok its the import java.nio.ByteBuffer; package. the other package does not have the allocate function :D

Answer (score 13):

Just to add another useful one based on @shazin solution. Convert a float array into a byte array:

```
public static byte[] FloatArray2ByteArray(float[] values){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * values.length);

    for (float value : values){
        buffer.putFloat(value);
    }

    return buffer.array();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Also based on Shazin solution, with additional specification on byte order:

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putFloat(value).array();
```

or

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).putFloat(value).array();
```

Answer (score 8):

It wont work. Float.byteValue just truncates float value to 1 byte

```
  public byte byteValue() {
        return (byte)value;
    }
```

Besides, it's not clear what bytes you want. Is it IEEE 754 floating-point single-float bit layout? Then you can first convert it to int

```
int i =  Float.floatToIntBits(1.1f);   // see Float API, there are actually 2 options
```

then use shifts to break it into 4 bytes or 8 bytes like you did

Comment: The OP wants all 8 bytes, not just one of them.

Comment: But this is exactly what he does not get, he shifts one and the same truncated byte 8 times

Comment: Yeah, I said that before you had the Float to int bits, so it was a bit more relevant then.

Comment: This is a more lightweight answer than the ByteBuffer one. From int to byte there is also an easier conversion.

Answer (score 7):

I cant see easy-to-use methods. It works:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(float value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putFloat(value);
    return bytes;
}

public static float toFloat(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getFloat();
}
```