# Decoding a real number from bytes in Java

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have a sensor that communicates to an Android App. The App collects the bytes received from the sensor into a byte buffer. The documentation for one of the various sensor readings states that the value is a **real number variable occupying 4 bytes**, therefore for that value I execute getFloat() in the buffer. However, the values that I get are too small to be correct, but they correlate well with other measurements that are correct. I have checked the byte order and it is correct. Note that other values are documented more specifically, such as **32bit unsigned integer**. Is there another way to decode 4 bytes into a real value in Java?

Code:

```
ByteBuffer packetBufferLittleEnd = ByteBuffer.wrap(finalPacket).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

measurement = packetBufferLittleEnd.getFloat();
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data? and have you tried it with different byte-order settings on the `ByteBuffer?`

Comment: Is there any more detail in the documentation? Do they mention IEEE 754, for example?

Comment: Well, if it's 4 bytes (32 bits) why not just do a conversion from binary to base 10? Computers use 2's-Complement, this is documented very well on the web. As @WhiteHotLoveTiger suggested, I would lookup IEEE 754 Standard for floating point numbers and their conversions to/from base 10. Also, you need to know whether you are using big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: '[Real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_data_type)' is quite generic.  Is it floating point or fixed point?

Comment: Exactly, real number is quite generic and that is why I am confused. I have mentioned that I have tried different byte orders (byte order is correct) and for other readings they have mentioned a more specific format, such as 32bit unsigned integer. My reading, although small correlate very well (0.81) with gold standard readings from an other sensor station.

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**
I browsed through S.O. and found another post that may give you the solution. Check this link: [How to convert 4 bytes array to float in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619653/converting-a-float-to-a-byte-array-and-vice-versa-in-java)

---

If trying to represent a signed integer in 2's-Complement, all positive numbers are represented as their unsigned versions. 
However,  to get a **negative value** in 2's-Complement you must follow the steps below:

1. Invert all of the bits of the number
2. Add a binary 1 to the inverted number.

This is demonstrated in the following example...

**1 as unsigned, 32-bit:**
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

**1 in 2's-Complement:**
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

**-1 in 2's-Complement:**

- *Inverting all bits of unsigned representation*: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
- *Adding binary 1*:    1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 *(This is -1 in 2's-Complement)*

For floating-point numbers, the process is a bit more time-consuming. You must utilize the IEEE 754 Standard conversion process to convert to and from base 10 to base 2 representations of the number. This is what you are goign to need to convert signed numbers from binary to a base ten representation.[Converting to/from IEEE 754](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/arun/Cpre305/ieee754/ie4.html)

Comment: @EJP Yes, I am aware of the definition of a real number. You still have to know 2's complement in order to utilize IEEE 754 to convert real numbers. I believe that it is unfair to downvote this answer; it provides solutions to OP's question and for other possible scenarios he/she could face (integers as well as floating-point numbers)

Comment: I am asking for a more specific Java way to convert the value. I have tried getFloat() from a byte buffer with both type of byte orderings and it doesn't work.

Comment: @KociKocev I just updated my answer with what you may be looking for, please see the link at the top of my answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing and it is not working, as I have mentioned.

Comment: @KociKocev It's hard to know what you are doing when you haven't posted any code :P

Comment: @KociKocev  Here is another similar post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619653/converting-a-float-to-a-byte-array-and-vice-versa-in-java

Comment: I have added the code, but it just reiterates what I have explained in the question.

Comment: @KociKocev did you see the link I posted in the comment above?

Comment: Yes I have, however, I will wait for input from the manufacturer, before continuing and trying new things.