# Efficient way to encode float to a UTF-8 byte buffer in java

Tags: java, performance, encoding, utf-8, floating-point

I want to encode float to UTF-8 byte array in java. Are there any libraries or packages that do this in an efficient way.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to encode a string representation of a float to a byte array using UTF-8, try `String.valueOf(someFloat).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Your approach has 3 steps: Implementation of String.valueOf 1) encode float to ASCII threadlocal buffer 2) ASCII -> Java string (UTF16) using new buffer 3) Java string -> UTF8 using new buffer I want to eliminate steps 2 and 3 because ASCII representation is equal to UTF8 representation in this case. So I want to play with ASCII buffer directly.

Comment: Does it need to be encoded as a string? Why not encode it bitwise?

Comment: That should be ok, can you provide an example on how can I go about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619653/converting-a-float-to-a-byte-array-and-vice-versa-in-java

Comment: Thats useful, but I do need to encode it as String. Sorry, I thought bitwise was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
String.valueOf(0.5f).getBytes("UTF-8");
```