# How to create a binary output in java that can be read directly in Python without using the unpack function?

Tags: python, java, binaryfiles

I am having an issue in Java converting a 2d float array in a binary format that Python could open without using unpack method. I [followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619653/how-to-convert-a-float-into-a-byte-array-and-vice-versa) the instruction and learned how to convert a float to a byte array but the results did not match when I open the output in Python. As I said I don't want to use the unpack function in Python. Is there any way to convert the results in Java to Python without using unpack function?

Given the input 2d array:

```
float[128][128] imageObjArray = ...;

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
        try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(outFilePath + outFileName)))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 128; k++) {
                        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Float.BYTES);
                        byteBuffer.putFloat(imageObjArray[j][k]);
                        out.write(byteBuffer.array());
                    }
                }
            out.flush();
        }
```

In Python, this may work but I want to get the results without using unpack:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
     numbers = struct.unpack('f' * 128 * 128, file.read(4 * 128 * 128))
```

Comment: what you are asking really doesn't make any sense. why don't you want to use `unpack`?  there is no way to directly read from a file and get a tuple of float objets, which is the result you get using `struct.unpack`. Probably, you should just use `numpy`, but that's a third-party library.

Comment: So 1) you haven't given any example input 2) you **haven't actually told us what output you want**. I noticed you *tagged* this with numpy, but you never mentioned it in your question.

Comment: Right.  There are some simple facts that you are trying to avoid here.  If you have binary data, then you need to use `struct.unpack` to turn it into a Python structure.  This is EXACTLY the inverse operation to the `putFloat` method you're using in Java.  It's not a problem, that's simply the way it is done.

Answer (score 2):

To start with DataOutputStream is Java-only (it was created to deal with the "endian" issue), so that's a problem. And unless you are doing inefficient writing (calling lots of little writes vs writing everything at once) just use a raw OutputStream (otherwise, add a BufferedOutputStream on top of this)

Second of all, you really ought to use a communication protocol (like XML or JSON) - data is so much easier to export and import this way.